# PyDev python interpreter argument/option field missing?

Tags: python, configuration, arguments, pydev, interpreter

I have issue to configure PyDev Python interpreter with Eclipse in order to be able to run script with "-m" python interpreter argument/option. Does anybody know where exactly one could set that argument? In command line one would do like this:
python -m some_package.tests.core_test

But in order to start same package in PyDev I am missing place where I could enter pythong argument "-m".

regards,
Milan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set that in the preferences.

i.e.: in `Preferences > PyDev > Run` select `Launch modules with "python -m mod.name" instead of "python filename.py"`.

After changing that, any Python launch done in PyDev should automatically compute the module name based on your PYTHONPATH and then use the module name in the launch along with the `-m`.